# How do I get LaTeX code to be stored literally in Python?

Tags: python, latex

I am using python and sqlite3 to make a database of physics solutions. I have a lot of LaTeX code that I would like to store, but I'm running into a problem. A lot of LaTeX code has characters that python interprets instead of just accepting as literal text. For example, I've tried the following to store \frac{}{}:

```
foo = "\frac{}{}"
foo2 = """\frac{}{}"""
foo3 = '''\frac{}{}'''
print foo
rac{}{}
foo
Out[10]: '\x0crac{}{}'
```

I would really like it to just be stored verbatim, as the original ascii characters. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to store them by prefixing the string with `r`:

```
In [1]: foo = r"\frac{}{}"

In [2]: foo
Out[2]: '\\frac{}{}'
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the quick answer... all three of you at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

I would simply use [raw strings](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

```
foo = r"\frac{}{}"
```

That'll stop Python from interpreting backslashes as escape sequences and will include them as-is.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [raw strings](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

Answer (score 1):

Just in order to be complete: you as well could write `'\\frac{}{}'`.

Or you can write a function

```
def latex_command(cmd, *args):
    return "\\" + cmd + "".join('{' + a + '}' for a in args)
latex_command('frac', '', '') # -> \frac{}{}
latex_command('frac', '3', '4') # -> \frac{3}{4}
latex_command('section', 'About') # -> \section{About}
```